# Auto Deploy Elastic Beanstalk Changes

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having a problem with elastic beanstalk, in my application there is some piece of code that creates some files dynamically and now I want to persist these files for future use, so is there any way that I can push my dynamically created files to GitHub automatically, so in next deployment these changes will remain, as elastic beanstalk replace the old code with new code after each deployment, So How can I commit my changes and push them to GitHub repo from code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can user aws S3 or other storage service as file back-end. This will sole you problem.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use storage server for the dynamically created file to Elastic Beanstalk, did you get my question correctly?

Comment: install boto3 using pip, and the following settings
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name of your bucket'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '"'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'

Comment: you can follow http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: I don't think you got my question, my question is My Django application is serving on EB, and some piece of code creates some new files in the EBS environment, and I want to push those newly created files (which are created in EB environment) to GitHub, so next deployment I can pull those file from git and redeploy them to EB, so in this way my files will not get lost.

Comment: My succession is save the files you are creating in S3, not on EBS, so the files will never lost.

Comment: Those are the Django-migrations file, So I don't think there would be a way to save the migrations source code file to s3 at runtime.

Comment: I run The makemigrations command on local environment, and only run migrate on remote server. Thats why I did not face this problem.